# java showing as 32 bit in task manager for my 64 bit machine

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, java, taskmanager

I have installed jdk 64 bit on my windows 7 running 64 bit OS.
I have also set the path environment variable as
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

Also when I check the version of java in cmd shows the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java Hotspot(TM) 64-bit serve VM
```

Now the problem is when I check in task manager it shows the process name as "java.exe *32"

Some of the applications I install complain that I am using 32 bit jdk on my 64 bit machine.

Comment: You probably have both versions installed.

Comment: Most applications scan the registry and prefer a standalone jre to one embedded in a jdk.  The path is normally _not_ used.  Uninstall your 32-bit standalone jre.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that you actually have both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Java installed, and that some applications are using the 32 bit version, due to the way that they / your system is configured.

You may not have explicitly installed 32 bit Java.  It is possible that some of the applications include an embedded 32 bit JRE installation.

---

If you have an application that insists that it won't run on a 32bit JRE, your options include:

- look for and uninstall any explicitly installed (standalone) 32-bit JREs,
- get hold of a 32-bit version of the application, or
- read the installation / configuration documentation for the application for clues on how to force it to use a specific installation.